# docker-compose service listen on specified interface

Tags: docker-compose

I use docker-machine and docker-compose.

The docker machine I use has multiple interfaces.

Is there a way to force services to listen only on a specific interface of the machine *without* defining the ip address of this interface in the port section?

Right now I use this in docker-compose.yml

```
    ports:
      - "10.5.1.28:80:80"
      - "10.5.1.28:2222:22"
      - "10.5.1.28:443:443"
```

But it is not very convenient as I have to rewrite all ips in case of change.

Is there any simplier way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One elegant solution is to create external network.

For example with two nginx using external networks (internet & intranet):

Services definition:

```
  nginx1:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - intranet    
  nginx2:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - internet
```

Network definition:

```
networks:
    internet:
      external: true
    intranet:
      external: true
```

Then prior first docker-compose up you will have to create the external network

In this example 192.168.178.69 is the ip on the internet side and 10.5.1.22 on the intranet side

```
docker network create -d bridge -o \
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=192.168.178.69 internet

docker network create -d bridge -o \
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=10.5.1.22 intranet
```